# Plotly extra space between boxes in plotly with subplots

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, subplot

I'm struggling with the boxplots because I have extra space between the boxes, and I want to remove it.

It looks like plotly understands there are six groups per x-tick event if there are three. The first subplot put the boxes on the left and the second on the right side of the ticks.

Any help would be appreciated.

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
     'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2']

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.03,)


fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
    x=x,
    name='kale',
    marker_color='#3D9970'
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2],
    x=x,
    name='radishes',
    marker_color='#FF4136',
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5],
    x=x,
    name='carrots',
    marker_color='#FF851B'
), row=1, col=1)

# same for second plot
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
    x=x,
    name='kale',
    marker_color='#3D9970'
), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2],
    x=x,
    name='radishes',
    marker_color='#FF4136',
), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5],
    x=x,
    name='carrots',
    marker_color='#FF851B'
), row=1, col=2)


fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title='normalized moisture',
    boxmode='group' # group together boxes of the different traces for each value of x
)
fig.show()
```

[image: The figure]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, add an offset group. By adding this, the graph becomes a graph of each attribute unit.

`offsetgroup='A'`

> offsetgroup – Set several traces linked to the same position axis or
> matching axes to the same offsetgroup where bars of the same position
> coordinate will line up. [reference](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Box.html)

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
     'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2']

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.03,)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
    x=x,
    name='kale',
    marker_color='#3D9970',
    offsetgroup='A'
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2],
    x=x,
    name='radishes',
    marker_color='#FF4136',
    offsetgroup='B'
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5],
    x=x,
    name='carrots',
    marker_color='#FF851B',
    offsetgroup='C'
), row=1, col=1)

# same for second plot
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
    x=x,
    name='kale',
    marker_color='#3D9970',
    offsetgroup='A'
), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2],
    x=x,
    name='radishes',
    marker_color='#FF4136',
    offsetgroup='B'
), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5],
    x=x,
    name='carrots',
    marker_color='#FF851B',
    offsetgroup='C'
), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title='normalized moisture',
    boxmode='group'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]